# what is the twurl command for triggering the twitter challenge response check (crc) for the invalid webhook id to make it valid again?

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

I registered my webhook url successfully, but as my server slept and i missed the twitter crc check which occurs in every 24 hours, due to which my webhook id became invalid. From the documentation i found the following curl command

```
curl --request PUT 
--url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/webhook/:WEBHOOK_ID.json --header 
 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_KEY",oauth_nonce="GENERATED", oauth_signature="GENERATED", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="GENERATED", oauth_token="ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"'
```

but I don't know how to generate oauth_nonce, oauth_signature. So i thought using Twurl which handles oauth 1.0 easily.

Does anyone knows the twurl command to do trigger the crc check for twitter?

Or does anyone knows the code for generating oauth_nonce and oauth_signature in python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation is incorrect (where did you find it?), but I can help you.

If you have `twurl` set up correctly, authenticated with the correct consumer key and secret that your webhook app is using and with the user ID you're using with it, then this command should work (I just tried it here and it works for me)

`twurl -X PUT "/1.1/account_activity/all/:ENV-NAME/webhooks/:WEBHOOK_ID.json"`

So in my case, with an environment name of `env-beta` and a known webhook ID, this triggered the CRC check:

`twurl -X PUT "/1.1/account_activity/all/env-beta/webhooks/10656zzzzMYIDzzz35232.json"`

Comment: Thank you so much Sir  @Andy Piper for helping me... actually i found the above curl command in the official twitter documentation    https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/api-reference/aaa-premium#get-account-activity-all-webhooks

Comment: I ran code * twurl -X POST "/1.1/account_activity/all/env/subscriptions.json" --header authorization: bearer_token * for subscribng twitter app for all activities.It gave me no response. Then i ran command 2 get list of subscriptns *** twurl -X POST "1.1/account_activity/all/subscriptions/count.json" --header authorization: bearer_token * it gave me error "could n't authenticate you" then i ran comand * twurl -X GET "1.1/account_activity/all/env/subscriptions/list.json" --header authorization: bearer_token* it gave error: your credntials do not allow acess to this resource... what should i do?

Comment: please sir can you give me a documentation on twurl commands?

Comment: Unfortunately twurl does not support bearer token authentication and it also does not support a —header parameter, but it should work as I posted above (I tried and tested that). You should already have set up twurl using the authorize command. You can get a tutorial on twurl using `twurl —tutorial`

Comment: (Actually I was mistaken about the comment about the header parameter - you can use it, but it will not work to insert a bearer token. Apologies for the confusion)

Comment: thank you sir, now I am finally getting the real time updates from my own account through premium sandbox account activity api... Currently I am the only user out of 15 who is subscribed to my Twitter app. Please sir can u tell me ,what is the procedure to make another user subscribe to my app so that I can get his/her account activities as I am getting mine?